# Read an online text file and put it into a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check an online txt file for the newest version code and show a dialog which says "Please update" or something similar. Is it posiible to put the content of the file into a variable?

EDIT: I tried Arpit Awasthi's solution but I get these errors:

```
lib/main.dart:685:25: Error: Method not found: 'HttpClient'.
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:687:23: Error: Method not found: 'consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes'.
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:688:5: Error: 'Directory' isn't a type.
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    ^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:690:5: Error: 'File' isn't a type.
    File file = File("${appDocDir.path}/$fileName");
    ^^^^
lib/main.dart:690:17: Error: Method not found: 'File'.
    File file = File("${appDocDir.path}/$fileName");
                ^^^^
lib/main.dart:691:5: Error: 'File' isn't a type.
    File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to download the file and then get the File object of that file.

```
static downloadFile(String url) async{
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String fileName = ('yourFileName.fileExtention');
    File file = File("${appDocDir.path}/$fileName");
    File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return urlFile;
  }
```

Note :- I've used this plugin to get app folder path :- path_provider: ^1.6.18

Comment: Sorry, but where do I put in my URL?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you can do is the following.
You May Define in a variable (context probably) you Current Version...
The you a async http request, you can call to an API where you check your latest release and if it is > that current one, trigger an alert dialog that shows that There is a new version available.